# PowerShell - Sorry, we couldn't find Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to modify the script created by [Boe Prox](https://learn-powershell.net/2010/09/04/converting-csv-file-or-files-into-an-excel-workbook/) that combines multiple CSV files to one Excel workbook to run on a network share.

When I run it locally, the script executes great and combines multiple .csv files into one Excel workbook.

```
Clear-Host
$OutputFile = "ePortalMonthlyReport.xlsx"
$ChildDir = "C:\MonthlyReport\*.csv"
cd "C:\MonthlyReport\"

echo "Combining .csv files into Excel workbook"
. C:\PowerShell\ConvertCSVtoExcel.ps1
Get-ChildItem $ChildDir | ConvertCSVtoExcel -output $OutputFile
echo " "
```

But when I modify it to run from a network share with the following changes:

```
Clear-Host
# Variables
$OutputFile = "ePortalMonthlyReport.xlsx"
$NetworkDir = "\\sqltest2\dev_ePortal\Monthly_Report"
$ChildDir = "\\sqltest2\dev_ePortal\Monthly_Report\*.csv"

cd "\\sqltest2\dev_ePortal\Monthly_Report"

echo "Combining .csv files into Excel workbook"
. $NetworkDir\ConvertCSVtoExcel.ps1
Get-ChildItem $ChildDir | ConvertCSVtoExcel -output $OutputFile
echo " "
```

I am getting an error where it looks like it using the network path twice and I am not sure why:

> Combining .csv files into Excel workbook
>
> Converting \sqltest2\dev_ePortal\Monthly_Report\001_StatsByCounty.csv
>   naming worksheet 001_StatsByCounty
>   --done
>
> opening csv Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\sqltest2\dev_ePortal\Monthly_Report\\sqltest2\dev_ePortal\Monthly_Report\001_StatsByCounty.csv) in excel in temp workbook
>
> Sorry, we couldn't find Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\sqltest2\dev_ePortal\Monthly_Report\\sqltest2\dev_ePortal\Monthly_Report\001_StatsByCounty.csv. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?

Anyone have any thoughts on resolving this issue?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in the script it uses the following regex:

```
[regex]$regex = "^\w\:\\"
```

which matches a path beginning with a driveletter, e.g. `c:\data\file.csv` will match and `data\file.csv` will not. It uses this because (apparently) Excel needs a complete path, so if the file path does not match, it will add the current directory to the front of it:

```
#Open the CSV file in Excel, must be converted into complete path if no already done
    If ($regex.ismatch($input)) {
        $tempcsv = $excel.Workbooks.Open($input) 
        }
    ElseIf ($regex.ismatch("$($input.fullname)")) {
        $tempcsv = $excel.Workbooks.Open("$($input.fullname)") 
        }    
    Else {    
        $tempcsv = $excel.Workbooks.Open("$($pwd)\$input")      
        }
```

Your file paths will be `\\server\share\data\file.csv` and it doesn't see a drive letter, so it hits the last option and jams `$pwd` - an automatic variable of the current working directory - onto the beginning of the file path.

You might get away if you edit his script and change the regex to:

```
[regex]$regex = "^\w\:\\|^\\\\"
```

which will match a path beginning with `\\` as OK to use without changing it, as well.

Or maybe edit the last option (~ line 111) to say `...Open("$($input.fullname)")` as well, like the second option does.

Comment: Thank you - Let me give this a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Much of the issues are caused in almost every instance where the script calls $pwd rather than $PSScriptRoot.  Replace all instances with a quick find and replace.

$pwd looks like:

```
PS Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\foo\bar
```

$PSScriptRoot looks like:

```
\\foo\bar
```

The second part i fixed for myself is what @TessellatingHeckler pointed out.  I took a longer approach.

It's not the most efficient way...but to me it is clear.

```
[regex]$regex = "^\w\:\\"
[regex]$regex2 = "^\\\\"

$test = 0

If ($regex.ismatch($input) -and $test -eq 0 ) {
$tempcsv = $excel.Workbooks.Open($input)
$test = 1 }

If ($regex.ismatch("$($input.fullname)") -and $test -eq 0) {
$tempcsv = $excel.Workbooks.Open("$($input.fullname)") 
$test = 1}

If ($regex2.ismatch($input) -and $test -eq 0) {
$tempcsv = $excel.Workbooks.Open($input)
$test = 1 }

If ($regex2.ismatch("$($input.fullname)") -and $test -eq 0) {
$tempcsv = $excel.Workbooks.Open("$($input.fullname)")
$test = 1}

If ($test -eq 0) {    
$tempcsv = $excel.Workbooks.Open("$($PSScriptRoot)\$input") 
$test = 0 }
```